# Is a file an image?

Tags: c#, image

In C# what is the best way to tell if a particular file is an image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most picture formats specify the file type in the first few bytes of the image.  You can read in a few bytes and look for the correct headers.

File extensions technically don't hold any important data about the image.  It just helps the OS figure out what program to use to open it. (But, checking the extn is probably the easiest way, and usually correct.)

Comment: It should be added, that even checking the header is no 100% guarantee. There is nothing stopping one from creating a file with the "correct" header, but random trash after that. In the end of course it all depends what you want to do with the "image" file - which the OP didn't tell - and be prepared that it may not be a "valid" image after all.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't tested, but it's something like this:

```
private string MimeType (string Filename)
{
    string mime = "[default]";
    string ext = GetExtension(Filename).ToLower();
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rk = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
    if (rk != null && rk.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
        mime = rk.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
    return mime;
}
```

(Sorry, it's been a while since I've done registry stuff.)

Comment: It is a good way to check image type based off extn...but if the extn is wrong the method will fail.

Comment: It also assumes that the extensions are registered correctly with the mime types in the registry, which is not always guaranteed to be the case.

Comment: It would be easier to simply try to load the file as a bitmap.  Using this method, once you have the mime type, you still have to make a decision based on that..

Answer (score 5):

The way we did it (and i cant find the exact code right now so the following is untested) is to try to load the image as a bitmap.  If it fails, its not an image

```
bool isImage;
try
{
  Bitmap.FromFile(filePath);
  isImage = true;
}
catch
{
  isImage = false;
}
```

Comment: ...or maybe it still is an image, but you won't be able to do anything with it. Is there a way to do it without loading the whole file?

Comment: Using Image.FromStream(stream, false, false) will be faster, since it doesn't try to validate all of the image data.

Comment: You can try any of the other methods listed here, but it depends on what you're trying to do.  Checking the extn will probably be enough for 90% of the applications out there

Comment: +1, but only for the Image.FromStream version. Much MUCH faster when working with large images or across slow network connections.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's any way of guaranteeing that a given file (or any set of bytes) necessarily represents an image other than trying to load and display it.

However, if you have some mystery bytes, you could always check for certain byte signatures to try to deduce if it is a well formed image file.  You can look up file headers on wikipedia, but here's some code I use in unit testing to verify the output of a third party reporting tool:

```
// Some signatures:

const string _pdfSignature = "%PDF-";
readonly byte[] _bmpSignature = new byte[2] { 0x42, 0x4D };
readonly byte[] _pngSignature = new byte[8] {0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A};
readonly byte[] _gifSignature = new byte[6] { 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61 };
```

And for JPGs:

```
Assert.That(_theBytes[0] == 0xFF && _theBytes[1] == 0xD8);    //Start of jpg file
Assert.That(_theBytes[_theBytes.Length - 2] == 0xFF && _theBytes[_theBytes.Length - 1] == 0xD9); //End of jpg file
```

Answer (score 2):

Most image files have a magic byte or two at the very beginning of the file. This is used by decoders and image viewers to identify the file type. There is no one rule that can help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to validate that the file is a valid image format then you are going to have to have some sort of code try and parse the contents according to the type of the file you are expecting.  To do that, you would call the static FromFile method on the Image class to try and get an Image instance.

You could check the first few bytes to see if the marker for a particular image format is there but just like checking the file extension, it doesn't guarantee that the contents are a valid image format.

If you don't need validation though, checking the file extension or mime type is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

check the file extension

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly I haven't done too much with this but isn't this simply looking up the mime-type?

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/